# In Crystal Reports, how do I keep a row from printing if the value is null?

Tags: null, crystal-reports-xi

I have a null value in my report.  I went to the formula workshop editor and put `IsNull({myreport.field})` but the row shows on the report.  It has "FALSE" or "TRUE," and it putting all the records on there.

How do I actually make it suppress or not show the records if the value is null?  What do I put in IF THEN (Is that what I use?)?  I don't want it on the report at all.

I am using Crystal Reports 2011 XI.

Comment: you can use supperss with condition :- if ({myreport.field}) is null then true

Comment: @Hirengardhariya Suppress is a keyword in CR XI?  Sorry, just learning.

Comment: if you don't want to show null value in your crystal report than you have to suppress this field or section or group.

Answer (score 4):

I usually use this formula to suppress blank sections.  It goes in the section expert supress formula editor.

```
IF ISNULL({myreport.myfield}) then TRUE   
ELSE IF {myreport.myfield} = " " then TRUE   
ELSE FALSE
```

Since you are in the suppression field you are telling it that supress = true if the conditions are met else they are not true and it should not be supressed.  I use the empty string condition to cover issues where it's not NULL but still blank.